# My mapped network drive keeps losing password to Win Server 2008 share

Tags: windows-server-2008, mappeddrive

We have WinXP machines on a domain which have a mapped network drive to a share on a Server 2008 computer that is not in the domain. The credentials on the share are a local account on the Server 2008 box.

The problem we are having is after a reboot of each computer in the domain, Windows asks for the account password password.

How can we make Windows remember our saved passwords?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you can't add the W2K8 box to the domain? And how secure are the passwords you are using to access it?

Answer (score 2):

For each XP workstation, use a startup batch file script in `%userprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` like so:

`net use <drive letter>: \\<servername or ip>\<sharename> /USER:<username> <password> /Y`

Answer (score 1):

Use a local login script. I have had this problem with shares on embedded devices not connected to my domain. Like: net use 'drive': \machine\share /USER:local\account "password" /persistent:yes